# Get values from html form to JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, html

I am having problems with passing values from HTML to JavaScript. This is a little RPG game I'm building and I want the user to type its name, age, class, and race in a form and create a Character object with his information.

```js
class Character {
  constructor(name, age, role, race) {
    this.name = document.getElementById("nameCharacter").value;
    this.age = document.getElementById("ageCharacter").value;
    this.role = document.getElementById("classCharacter").value;
    this.race = document.getElementById("raceCharacter").value;
  }
}
var hero;
function create() {
  hero = new Character();
}
```

```css
body{
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.form-group{
    margin-left:350px;
    margin-right:350px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.form-check{
    margin-left:350px;
}

#boton{
    margin-left:350px;
    margin-top:15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Iniciando</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      media="screen"
      href="criarPersonagem.css"/>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <script src="criarPersonagem.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="mg.jpg" alt="Logo" style="width:40px;" />
      </a>
      <!-- Links -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="rascunho.html">Battle RPG</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Welcome to the game!</h1>
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Create your own Character</h3>
    <form action="" name="criarPP">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="nameCharacter"
          placeholder="Your character's name"
        />
        <small id="nomePP" class="form-text text-muted"
          >This will be your nickname inside the game</small
        >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input
          type="number"
          class="form-control"
          id="ageCharacter"
          placeholder="Your character's age"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="classCharacter">
          <option value="Null" hidden>Your character's class</option>
          <option value="Mage">Mage</option>
          <option value="Assassin">Assassin</option>
          <option value="Warrior">Warrior</option>
          <option value="Paladin">Paladin</option>
          <option value="Necromancer">Necromancer</option>
          <option value="Druid">Druid</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="raceCharacter">
          <option value="Null" hidden>Your character's race</option>
          <option value="Human">Human</option>
          <option value="Elf">Elf</option>
          <option value="Orc">Orc</option>
          <option value="Dwarf">Dwarf</option>
          <option value="Argonian">Argonian</option>
          <option value="Darl elf">Dark elf</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <button
        type="submit"
        class="btn btn-primary"
        id="boton"
        onclick="create()"
      >
        Create
      </button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried somethings and after several tries and failures. I started to think there is something missing in the form tag or even in the button tag

The expected results are simple: successfully create the object via the form. I usually try to show it on a console to see if it works.

Comment: That's it! I chaged the button type from "submit" to "button" and it works now. Thank you guys! Now i'm more pissed of because i've been stuck in this for 5 days and all i had to do was chage one single name hahaha thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button type is submit so it's creating the object but page is submitting and the object is gone. Try to change button type submit to button i think.

Comment: I think even if you change the button type the form will submit, a better method might be returning `false` from the `create` function

Answer (score 0):

Change button type to "button", this:

```
<button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary"
        id="boton"
        onclick="create()"
>
    Create
</button>
```

This way it will not submit the form.

You can also achieve the same by `return false;` or by calling `e.preventDefault()`